# How to start a function for 'n' amount and stop it on button press in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My app consists of two buttons say 'Start' and 'Stop' and what I want to do is **when I tap 'Start' it should execute a function every 10 seconds and when I tap 'Stop' the function should stop executing**. However I am not able to do so.

I searched for my answer but unfortunately was not successful. **I only found how to run a function every 'n' amount but can't figure out how to implement the button function to start and stop**.

```
child: Center(
                    child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      onPressed: () => fetchData.getDataFromNse(),
                      label: Text('Start'),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.launch),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
child: Center(
                    child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      onPressed: () => fetchData.getDataFromNse(),
                      label: Text('Stop'),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                  ),
```

This is my **fetchData** function which I want it to be executed every 10 seconds when 'Start' is pressed and stop it when 'Stop' is pressed.

```
class fetchData {
  static void getDataFromNse(){
    print("Hello!"); # This is just an example!
  }
}
```

I need help if someone can!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start a [Timer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html) with your start button invoking the method every 10 seconds. Cancel the timer with your stop button

Comment: Wow that was easy, thanks !